# npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.22000

Tags: angular, npm

```
PS C:\workspace\TrazabilidadBioled\trazabilidadBioled\assets\FrontEnd> npm install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! syscall write

npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! syscall write

npm ERR! write EPROTO 101057795:error:1408D07B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_key_exchange:bad signature:openssl\ssl\s3_clnt.c:2032:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\workspace\TrazabilidadBioled\trazabilidadBioled\assets\FrontEnd\npm-debug.log
PS C:\workspace\TrazabilidadBioled\trazabilidadBioled\assets\FrontEnd>
```

I was trying to install angular cli 1.0.3 on windows 11, I got a new laptop but when I trying to install make these error, I do the same thing on windows 10 and 0 problem, also I had one pc with windows 10 and I upgrade to windows 11 and install the environment dev with 0 problem, I do my research but I can’t got nothing, anyone know something I can do for solve these problem?
I use NVM, I reinstall and clear the cache but nothing, the only thing I can mention is when I install latest version of node and install latest version of angular, I get 0 error…
Also, I try to fix the problem with the proxy like appears in some post of stack but I don’t get the problem solved, I was looking for some solution for about 2 week, so I thing is time to ask us, thanks bros

> The error is not with the command of installation of angular because I do the installation manually thinking these was a solution but with the npm install I get the same error when I try to install angular

Comment: Hello, could you provide the version of node / npm ? Also, are you sure you're talking about Angular 1.0.3 ?

Comment: node v6.10.3, npm  v3.10.10 even if angular does not work, is the comand of npm, the angular i try to install was npm install --global @angular/cli@1.0.3, but it is the same, i install angular manually and i can run proyect with node_modules donwloaded manually but if i try to run any comand with npm fail

Comment: was it solved? I'm currently having similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73302014/npm-err-windows-nt-10-0-22000-npm-v3-10-8-node-v6-9-1